# not fulfilled Promises without catch block (unhandledrejection) javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-promise

I  write project in VueJs Javascript and would like to see in the console messages, if any of my Promises are not fulfilled and do not have catch block.

I tried something like this

```
Promise.reject("error!");
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
  console.log('i am error')
});
```

but without success. 
Are there any other approach? Or how could I fix this one?

Comment: This works fine in Chrome and that's the only browser currently implementing `unhandledrejection`. In which browser did you try that?

Comment: @t.niese oh, well, that explains a lot, i try it currently in Firefox, but I need also for Chrome, Edge..

Answer (score 0):

`unhandledrejection` is for the native Promises currently only implemented in Chrome. If you want to log those error also in other browser you would need to overwrite the native Promise with another implementation like bluebird:

```js
Promise.reject("error!");
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
  console.log('i am error')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.5.1/bluebird.js"></script>
```

You need to make sure that bluebird is loaded as the first script.

[bluebird: Error management configuration](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html)